# Changing the date names in QCalendar widget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to change names of weekdays and months, in accordance to my locale (croatian locale) within `QCalendar` widget of the `PyQt4 project`.

The documentation referring to the problem does have some methods to change the first day of the week and so on, but I never found a way to actually do it.

Is there any way to change it from inside the code or are the names associated with a particular locale that is set up on one Linux or Windows system?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do this. Qt should determine the correct locale to use from your system settings. If the correct locale is set, the calendar-widget will show the correctly translated names. You can check this by manually setting the default locale, like so:

```
    QtCore.QLocale.setDefault(QtCore.QLocale('hr_HR'))
```

But as I say, it really shouldn't be necessary to do this. You can check the default system locale that Qt is using by doing:

```
    loc = QtCore.QLocale.system()
    print(loc.name())
```

If this does not show the correct language, then either your system locale settings are incorrect, or the version of Qt you are using is buggy. One example of a bug that might affect you is [this one](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-1313), which was not properly fixed until Qt-4.8.5.

Comment: thanks, that solved it. it seems that the student's server on my faculty runs en_US locale, not hr_HR. adding the above mentioned lines in the code was enough to solve the problem :-)